# Rosbag live data

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to plot string values using rqt_plot ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270801/rosbag-live-data/) by [Obedulla](https://answers.ros.org/users/31284/obedulla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short, no. I couldn't do it.

What does the string (`std_msgs/String`) look like, `"hello, ROS"` or something else? I tried publishing via the terminal and then tried to use `rqt_plot` to "plot" the string and got nothing. This makes sense because plotting a string like `"hello, ROS"` is nonsense. I even published a number as a string and tried to plot that too and still got nothing.

Finally, when I published a `std_msgs/Float32` message and tried plotting that, I succeeded.

By the way, I'm using Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0